# Using PHP to parse multiple xml files

Tags: php, xml

I'm working on Mac and using Code Runner to do my PHP coding. I need to load multiple XMLs simultaneously with these:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    /*
    //to convert $a into $file after code is working proper
    $type = 'syll';
    $level = 'P1';
    $file = 'xml_'.$level.'_'.$type.'/';
    */
    $a = glob('xml_P1_syll/*.xml');
    //echo $file.'<br>';
    //print_r($a);
    foreach ($a as $i) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("$i")or die("Error: Cannot load file");

            foreach ($xml->children() as $entry => $data) {
                echo $data->section.'<br>';
                echo $data->source.'<br>';
                echo $data->question.'<br>';
                echo $data->instruction.'<br>';
            }
    }

?>
```

It worked successfully when i'm running from code runner itself… But when i upload to server it returned this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file.php on line 12
```

I've only started using foreach() since all the tutorials for php parsing xml strongly recommends using it. I've been using only for() all this while. Could it be syntax for foreach()? Or is it with php version (since it worked in code runner). Any pointers is greatly appreciated…Thanks

Comment: check if `$a` or `$xml` aren't empty.

Comment: With what you say, glob() seems to return an empty array, like if it finds nothing.

Comment: as i mentioned earlier, it worked locally… Its only when i upload to server that it comes up with errors. So its either my foreach() is not stable or there's a difference in PHP version which i need advise in sorting this conflict...

Comment: Which `foreach` is on line 12? The `foreach ($a as $i)` or `foreach ($xml->children() ...`?

Comment: Then the result of `glob()` was `false`, indicating some error has occurred or if there were no results.

Comment: @Jack, yes ur right. locally print_r($a) would print the array but on server its blank. What could be the problem? Read permission?

Answer (score 0):

can't comment as I don't have a rep of 50 yet,
I suggest checking your directory reference to be correct xml_P1_syll/*.xml
assuming /var/www or what have you as your base. Check the DocumentRoot setting.

Comment: i have the same file structures locally and remotely… It worked fine locally and the same directory structure is being used to write to these XML files remotely. Now i'm just trying to retrieve and parse them into tables. If the problem is due to directory referencing, it won't work at writing...